# Object reference not set to an instance of an object

Tags: asp.net

hello 
 can any one help me :)

whats the problem in this code ??

```
protected void LinkButton1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    //object o = new object();
    //Control co = new Control();
    //co = GridView1.FindControl("EmpFileUpload");
    FileUpload f = new FileUpload();
    (System.Web.UI.WebControls.FileUpload)f = (System.Web.UI.WebControls.FileUpload)(GridView1.FindControl("EmpFileUpload"));

    if (f.HasFile)
    {
        SqlConnection conn = new SqlConnection(ConfigurationManager.ConnectionStrings["schoolsConnectionString"].ConnectionString);
        conn.Open();
        SqlCommand insertCommand = new SqlCommand("insert_Empimg", conn);

        insertCommand.Parameters.Add("Emp_imgPath", SqlDbType.NVarChar, 0).Value =f.FileName;

        insertCommand.CommandType = CommandType.StoredProcedure;
        insertCommand.ExecuteNonQuery();

        conn.Close();
    }



}
```

Comment: It is difficult to know just by looking at the code. You should look at the exception's stack trace, and find out which line is exactly throwing the exception.

Comment: Welcome to Stackoverflow! Let me give you some hints that might help you get good answers to your question: (a) If you get an error message, tell us *in which line of your code* this error occurs (this usually shown by Visual Studio). (b) Please format your code. This has been done by Richard for your right now; next time, please do it yourself.

Answer (score 1):

Firstly

```
FileUpload f = new FileUpload();
(System.Web.UI.WebControls.FileUpload)f = (System.Web.UI.WebControls.FileUpload(GridView1.FindControl("EmpFileUpload"));
```

You don't need to 'new' `f` if you're reassigning it on the next line.

```
FileUpload f = (System.Web.UI.WebControls.FileUpload(GridView1.FindControl("EmpFileUpload"));
```

Secondly, you need to check `f` isn't null by the sounds of it.

```
if(f != null && f.HasFile)
```

Answer (score 1):

It's possible that your FindControl is not finding the upload control.

Lets tidy this code up a bit..

```
//You dont need the `new` as you are assigning to the result of `FindControl`
FileUpload f = GridView1.FindControl("EmpFileUpload") as FileUpload;

//Check for null here, this is probably your problem
if (f !=null && f.HasFile)     
{       
    //Using statement takes care of closing our connection and disposing our objects.
    using (SqlConnection conn = new SqlConnection(ConfigurationManager.ConnectionStrings["schoolsConnectionString"].ConnectionString))
    {
         conn.Open();         
         using (SqlCommand insertCommand = new SqlCommand("insert_Empimg", conn))
         {          
             insertCommand.Parameters.Add("Emp_imgPath", SqlDbType.NVarChar, 0).Value =f.FileName;          
             insertCommand.CommandType = CommandType.StoredProcedure;         
             insertCommand.ExecuteNonQuery();
         }
    }
}
```

Then we can have a look at why it is not being found, could you paste your markup that declares your `EmpFileUpload`

Comment: And you may need to find the row of the control you are looking for and do a find control there.  Gridviews can be picky about it.  There could but several controls in a gridview with that id.  But only one in any given row.

Answer (score 0):

```
FileUpload f = (System.Web.UI.WebControls.FileUpload)(GridView1.FindControl("EmpFileUpload"));
```

And finding the control by `GridView1.FindControl("EmpFileUpload")` depends on where you put your `file upload` in the `grid view` . please put your `aspx` shot to identify clearly where you put your control.to access it in the correct way.